# Reading pending work from PhantomJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, phantomjs

I am building a pool of PhantomJS instances, and I am trying to make it so that each instance is autonomous (it fetches next job to be done).

My concern is to choose between these two:

- Right now I have a Rails app that can give to PhantomJS which URL needs to be parsed next. So, I could do an HTTP get call from PhantomJS to my Rails app and Rails would respond with a URL that is pending to be done (most likely Rails would get that from a queue).
- I am thinking on building a stand alone Redis server that PhantomJS would access via Webdis, so Rails would push the jobs there, and PhantomJS instances would fetch from it directly.

I am trying to think what would be the correct decision in terms of performance: PhantomJS hitting the Rails server (so Rails needs to get the job from the queue and send it to PhantomJS), or just making PhantomJS to access a Redis server directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I need more info but why isn't the performance answer obvious?  Phantom JS hitting the Redis server directly means less stuff to go through.

I'd consider developing whatever is easier to maintain.  What's the ballpark req/minute?  What sort of company (how funded / resource-strapped are you)?

There's also more OOTB solutions like IronMQ that may ease the pain